# How to determine if a Windows Domain is still active?

Tags: windows, active-directory

We inheritied a file server that has permissions from a domain I do not recognize (e.g., `SCICENTER/jdoe`).

I suspect this might be a domain that has since been retired. How could I confirm that the domain is not active?

Comment: since its not resolving to an unidentified sid then that means something about it is valid.

Comment: @Tony - very good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be a NetBIOS name of a domain trust. Check current trusts with the following command:

```
nltest /server:localhost /trusted_domains
```

The output will report all trusted domains on a separate line. The output is formatted as follows, with the 0 being the line number:

```
 0: NETBIOSNAME FQDN.COM (Domain Type) (Other Attributes)
```

The server's primary/native domain will be noted in the Other Attributes field as well.

Once you have the FQDN of the SCICENTER domain, then you can just try to resolve it through DNS and/or ping it.

Alternatively, you can also list all domain controllers that the computer knows of for a given domain name (NetBIOS or FQDN) using the following command:

```
 nltest /dclist:SCICENTER
 nltest /dclist:sciencecenter.org
  et cetera
```

Note: If you use the NetBIOS name, then you may only get the PDC for a trusted domain.

Comment: The file server is now joined to our domain. When I go on the file server to to `nltest`, the command does not exist. Should I do this on one DC's instead?

Comment: You can just copy the binary of nltest.exe from one of your DCs. Not sure if 32-bit vs 64-bit is an issue though.

Comment: It's part of RSAT and any server with ADDS/ADLDS installed. As mfinni said, you can just copy the executable, or install RSAT as noted here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee649281%28WS.10%29.aspx - Also: note the "/server:" switch. You can point that to the server in question from your DCs just fine.

Answer (score 1):

From that server you inherited: If you don't see it in DNS, and you can't make it respond via WINS, then even if it still existed, you can't reach it.

If it does respond, it still exists.

Here's a test - try adding a file permission and see if it will let you pick that domain from the GUI, and if any users populate when you query.